# An uncaught Exception was encountered Type: Google_Auth_Exception Message: Error fetching OAuth2 access token, message: 'invalid_grant: Bad Request'

Tags: oauth2-playground

An uncaught Exception was encountered

Type: Google_Auth_Exception

Message: Error fetching OAuth2 access token, message: 'invalid_grant: Bad Request'

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! Please, could you provide a minimal reproducible example?We are glad to help if you give us the tools, in this case the code that creates the exception.

Comment: while trying to login with google (using code-igniter google library)  , getting this error message .authenticate() function in  Google/Auth/OAuth2.php throwing exception .